# Instantaneous enthalpy and entropy change of reaction as equilibrium is established

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, energy

Can we calculate instantaneous difference between enthalpy and entropy of product and reactants of a reaction as the reaction proceeds towards equilibrium? Ex: $\ce{R<->P}$ reaction, at some reaction coordinate, moles of $R = 1-x , P = x$, Enthalpy difference between products and reactants? Enthalpy difference if it reached equilibrium? Values of $$\Delta G^0, \Delta H^0, \Delta S^0$$ are known. Or is it impossible and the only relationship available is $$\Delta H = T \Delta S$$ at equilibrium or are their values only temperature dependent and activity independent?

We can do this for Gibbs free energy by $$\Delta G=\Delta G^0+\mathcal RT\ln Q$$

Comment: In order to do this, you need to accept the idea that the thermodynamic functions and be defined and calculated even for non-equilibrium states of a system.  I have no problem accepting this, but certainly some physicists would not be willing to make this leap.

Comment: G is also a thermodynamic function right?

Comment: Sure G is a thermodynamic function.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_molar_property It seems that Chemical Potential is bridging the gap and it's only connection is to G. H needs entropy to be constant. Any thoughts?

Comment: I agree with everything in the reference you provided.  G is the most useful and convenient function for defining the chemical potential.  In fact, the chemical potential is just the partial molar Gibbs free energy.